How to fix the Playback error with audio_waveforms in Flutter?
I'm using the audio_waveforms package with version 1.0.5 and I'm creating an app that records sounds and displays sound waves, but when I play the recorded sound it shows me the following error:
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9333): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9333):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
...more

I understand that it is because it does not find the recorded sound, but I have tried everything and the problem continues.
  RecorderController recorderController = RecorderController(); // Initialise
  PlayerController playerController = PlayerController(); // Initialise
  late Directory appDirectory;
 String? _filePath;


@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getDir();
    _initialiseControllers();
  }

  void _getDir() async {
    appDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); //I think the problem is here
    _filePath = "${appDirectory.path}/recording.m4a";
    setState(() {});
  }

  void _initialiseControllers() {
    recorderController = RecorderController()
      ..androidEncoder = AndroidEncoder.aac
      ..androidOutputFormat = AndroidOutputFormat.mpeg4
      ..iosEncoder = IosEncoder.kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC
      ..sampleRate = 44100;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    recorderController.dispose();
    playerController.dispose();
  }


Future<void> startRecording() async {
    final bool isPermissionGranted = await recorderController.checkPermission();
    if (!isPermissionGranted) {
      return;
    }

    setState(() {
      isRecording = true;
    });

    await recorderController.record(
      path: _filePath,
    );
    setState(() {
      isRecording = true;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _pauseRecording() async {
    await recorderController.pause();
    print(_filePath);
    await playerController.preparePlayer(
      path: _filePath!,
    );

    setState(() {
      isRecording = false;
      isRecordingPaused = true;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _playRecording() async {
    if (_filePath != null) {
      await playerController.startPlayer();
      setState(() {
        isRecordingPlaying = true;
      });
      await playerController.preparePlayer(
        path: _filePath!,
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> _stopRecording() async {
    await playerController.stopPlayer();
    setState(() {
      isRecordingPlaying = false;
    });
  }

  LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
                              return AudioWaveforms(
                                  recorderController: recorderController,
                                  size: Size(
                                      100.0.w, constraints.maxHeight * 0.5),
                                 //blah blah It's just the style
                                  ));
                            }),
                       Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        if (!isRecordingPaused) ...[
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              if (!isRecording) {
                                startRecording();
                              } else {
                                _pauseRecording();
                              }
                            },
                            child: Container(
                             
                              child: Icon(
                                isRecording ? Icons.pause : Icons.mic,
                                color: MaterialTheme.darkScheme().tertiary,
                                size: 30,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ] else ...[
                        //other button to send audio to db
                      ],
                    ),
                            Container(
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  if (isRecordingPlaying) {
                                    _stopRecording();
                                  } else {
                                    _playRecording(); //listen to the recorded sound
                                  }
                                
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Icon(
                                        isRecordingPlaying
                                            ? Icons.pause
                                            : Icons.play_arrow,
                                        
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),



I have tried changing the code  * await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();*, but it shows me the same result, I also tried to downgrade the version to 1.0.4, but got the same result.
